# react-router - separate files

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have the following `app.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss, Link } from 'react-router'

//import Jobs from './modules/Jobs'
//import Job from './modules/Job'

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Main</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/jobs">Jobs</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Main} />
      <Match pattern="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)


const Jobs = ({ pathname }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Jobs</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job1`}>job1</Link></li>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job2`}>job2</Link></li>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job3`}>job3</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <Match pattern={`${pathname}/:jobId`} component={Job}/>
    <Match pattern={pathname} exactly render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a job</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

It works great.

How can I put this bit in a separate file?

```
const Jobs = ({ pathname }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Jobs</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job1`}>job1</Link></li>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job2`}>job2</Link></li>
      <li><Link to={`${pathname}/job3`}>job3</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <Match pattern={`${pathname}/:jobId`} component={Job}/>
    <Match pattern={pathname} exactly render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a job</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)
```

I would like a folder called `modules` like so:

- modules

  - Main.js
  - Jobs.js
  - Job.js
  - etc.

I used to do this kind of thing:

```
//Jobs.js
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Jobs</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

and then I'd include it in my `app.js` with: `import Jobs from './modules/Jobs'`

But as I'm new to React, I'm not sure of the syntax...

Comment: That is correct. Everything you said works as expected, or should. Have you tried and it doesn't?

Comment: I think it's the `const Jobs = ({ pathname }) => (` bit in the `Jobs.js` file. I think I'm missing imports or something. I think I'm doing something wrong that might not seem obvious.

Comment: So what's the error exactly? I'm confused as to what you had before working vs what you have now not working

Comment: I see the following in the browser console: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Match`, expected `function`." It's as if the `pathname` parameter is causing problems.

Comment: Yeah I still don't see enough of the code to truly understand the issue. You can try switching from the React native `createClass` method to a Pure component (that's what you show on the top). In your case, something like `export default function Jobs() { return <div><h2>Jobs</h2></div> }`

Comment: Did you include import Job from './modules/Job'  in jobs.js?